# ArcGIS Server not publishing map services

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

In the past week, I managed to set up ArcGIS Server on the server but subsequently encountered errors when publishing a web map in ArcMap.

I have set up the ArcGISSOC and ArcGISSOM accounts and given rights to the specific folders. However I encountered the following problems that I have attached screen shots and highlighted in RED.

The error reads:

> The SOC account cannot resolve the path to the data, or the SOC
> account has not been granted read permission to the data. In the case
> of ARCSDE, direct connect may not be configured properly or the SOC
> account may not have permission to access the database.

I also noticed under the (ArcGISSOM Inheritance) screen shot, under the inherited from tab, the status reads as `<not inherited>`, what could be the cause of this because from my understanding, the webmapping folder should have rights from the server drive. I also tried publishing from the ArcGIS server manager but it was unsuccessful.

Can you assist in solving the problems that I am encountering so that I can effectively do the web mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Your ArcGISSOC account needs to have read and write permissions within your SDE database.  I'm not sure what your database server is, but for MS SQL Server 08 R2 you can add the login account using MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Another thing to test is if you can create a map service from non SDE data (e.g. shapefile or geodatabase).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is file-based (shapefile, or file geodatabase), you should configure your map document to use relative paths to the data.

Then, when you load your map document and data onto the server, preserve the same folder structure.  So, if your geodata is in a "data" subfolder, ArcGIS Server will be able to find it - otherwise it will look in "C:\originalpath\data" or wherever you saved it on your system.